# update bindings of CLR property within few milliseconds WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, timer

I am developing a WPF application in which i have to show a control for 80 miliseconds and after that hide.

There are 16 controls and their respective ViewModels and in each viewmodel there is a timer(System.Timers.Timer) and CLR property which is bind to control's Visibilty.

Timer gets start when a value is greater than 0 and set CLR property to Visible and Elapsed event is fired after 80 miliseconds in which set the property to Collapsed.

In below code, Method1() is called after 400 miliseconds.

for example:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    Timer timer;
    private Visibility _isVisibile = Visibility.Collapsed;
    public Visibility IsVisibile
    {
        get { return _isVisibile; }
        set { SetField(ref _isVisibile, value, () => IsVisibile); }
    }

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 80;
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsVisibile = Visibility.Collapsed;
        timer.Stop();            
    }

    public void Method1(int value)
    {
        if (value > 0)
        {
            IsVisibile = Visibility.Visible;
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Property change event of IsVisible is fired every time but it does not reflect on UI in 80 miliseconds if there are more than 2 controls.

How much time it takes to update visibility binding of a control?
How can I achieve this to update binding with in few milliseconds so that it can work with all 16 controls parallel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't know the answer but I suspect it is something like 'it's complicated'. Before you even start talking about binding updates you need to know what the max resolution of a `Timer` is.  I am having a hard time finding an exact answer (I suspect the answer is 'it's complicated') but after reviewing half a dozen blogs and responses it looks like it may be somewhere between 15ms and 50ms.  So you are already well outside your 'few milliseconds' constraint before you have even updated the `Visibility` property.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but my impression is that you are trying to synchronize these objects for some sort of animation.  If that is the case having 16 viewmodels with corresponding views is probably not the way to go.  Can you encapsulate all this logic in a single control?

Comment: You should not be using a `Timer`here, because its `Elapsed` handler is not running in the UI thread, and you would therefore have to call `Dispatcher.Invoke` to call the handler code in the UI thread. Use a `DispatcherTimer` instead. Its `Tick` handler does run in the UI thread.

Comment: The WPF Binding Engine cannot guarantee any timings. It's driven by a `Dispatcher` that queues the actions on the UI thread according to their priorities. The binding priority is not the highest, however. **TL;DR**: don't use WPF bindings if you have strict timing requirements.

Comment: I can't see this being possible to the level of precision that you clearly desire if it is controlled from viewmodel dependency bindings.  Take a look at animations within the view, so you have a default state of collapsed, and then when you enter the animation storyboard you set it visible, and then revert after 80ms.  I think that's the best you're going to get.